# How to eliminate multiple call for function with few INOUT parameters in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, inout

I porting a code from Oracle to PosgreSQL (classic, Carl).
I found, that my function called 3 times, I make this simple example:
Look please at my example:

```
create function trak_test001(inout int,inout int, inout int)
AS
$BODY$
<<trak_test001>>
DECLARE
  x ALIAS FOR $1;
  y ALIAS FOR $2;
  z ALIAS FOR $3;

BEGIN
  Raise DEBUG  'trak_test001 FOR x=% y=% z=% ',x,y,z;
  x:=x+1;
  y:=y+1;
  z:=z+1;
END trak_test001;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE 
COST 1000;

create function trak_test002()
RETURNS void
AS
$BODY$
<<trak_test002>>
DECLARE
  x int default 0;
  y int default 0;
  z int default 0;

BEGIN
  Raise DEBUG  'trak_test002 FOR x=% y=% z=% ',x,y,z;
 SELECT (trak_test001(x,y,z)).* INTO x,y,z;
    Raise DEBUG  'trak_test002 FOR x=% y=% z=% ',x,y,z;
END trak_test002;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE 
COST 1000;

SELECT trak_test002();
```

And got next debug output:

```
DEBUG:  trak_test002 FOR x=0 y=0 z=0
DEBUG:  trak_test001 FOR x=0 y=0 z=0 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (trak_test001(x,y,z)).*"
PL/pgSQL function trak_test002() line 10 at SQL statement
DEBUG:  trak_test001 FOR x=0 y=0 z=0 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (trak_test001(x,y,z)).*"
PL/pgSQL function trak_test002() line 10 at SQL statement
DEBUG:  trak_test001 FOR x=0 y=0 z=0 
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (trak_test001(x,y,z)).*"
PL/pgSQL function trak_test002() line 10 at SQL statement
DEBUG:  trak_test002 FOR x=1 y=1 z=1
Total query runtime: 56 msec
```

So this is question: Why my function calls 3 times and howto avoid this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot. Right way to call function with multiple INOUT parameters is:

```
create function trak_test002()
RETURNS void
AS
$BODY$
<<trak_test002>>
DECLARE
  x int default 0;
  y int default 0;
  z int default 0;

BEGIN
  Raise DEBUG  'trak_test002 FOR x=% y=% z=% ',x,y,z;
 SELECT * INTO x,y,z FROM trak_test001(x,y,z);
    Raise DEBUG  'trak_test002 FOR x=% y=% z=% ',x,y,z;
END trak_test002;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE 
COST 1000;
```